# assigning value to undefined and type of undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, undefined, ecmascript-next

In `"non-strict"` mode of javascript, We can assign value to `undefined`. I tried to assign it value but when I tried to print that value it's giving me strange results.

```js
let a = 10;
undefined = 20;
a = undefined;
console.log(a); //  undefined not 20
console.log(undefined); // undefined not 20
```

If I create my own scope then `undefined` can be overwritten. I know that since ECMA 5 you cannot override `undefined` it's read-only. Then how I am getting the following output(set undefined to 10) for my own scope?

Does it means that I can write that in my own scope(non-global) only?

```js
(function (undefined) {
  undefined = 10;
  console.log("Value of undefined: " + undefined);
})();
```

Comment: You can't reassign the *global* `undefined`.

Comment: _“In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5 specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.”_ — [MDN docs for `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks! Sorry, didn't know that.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it's not. It's a property of the `window` object - in more recent environments, it's write protected but it didn't use to be.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks! Sorry, didn't know that.

Comment: Everyone is saying, I can't reassign global `undefined`, in my question I mentioned that `In not strict mode`. I know that we can't override default undefined, but what happens in non-strict mode, Thanks to @CertainPerformance, for understanding it and answering question.

Comment: I tried to raise an issue to fix the section of the book that confused you, but it seems the maintainer is not accepting any changes for that section because it's from the 1st edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as expected. References to `undefined` is actually `window.undefined`, and the `undefined` property of `window` is non-writable:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'undefined'));
```

And non-writable properties can't be overwritten.

The difference is that in strict mode, trying to write to it throws an error, whereas in sloppy mode, the failure is silent.

The same sort of behavior can be seen if you assign another non-writable property to `window` and try to overwrite it:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'prop', { value: 'value', writable: false });
window.prop = 5;
console.log(window.prop);

(() => {
  'use strict';
  window.prop = 10;
})();
```

Although [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/types-grammar/ch2.md#undefined) says you can "assign a value to the globally provided undefined identifier", this is only true for ES3 environments and below. In ES5+ (which pretty much all browsers support nowadays), `undefined` is *not* overwritable.